# Generate a file from a yaml template

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

Is there a possibility in Helm to generate a file from a yaml template?
I need to create a configuration that is dynamic depending on the setup.
I need to add it as a secret/configuration file to the container when starting it.

Update:
This is the file contents that I would like to parameterize:

```
version: 1.4.9
port: 7054
debug: {{ $debug }}
         ...
tls:
  enabled: {{ $tls_enable }}
  certfile: {{ $tls_certfile }}
  keyfile: {{ $tls_keyfile }}
  ....
ca:
  name: {{ $ca_name }}
  keyfile: {{ $ca_keyfile }}
  certfile: {{ $ca_certfile }}
....
affiliations:
   {{- range .Values.Organiza }}: []
```

All these values are

I don't have a clue how to pass this file contents into ConfigMap or any other k8s object that would generate a final version of the file.

Comment: The Helm documentation has a large section on [its templating system](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/).  You can apply the templating constructs pretty much anywhere, including inside the body of a ConfigMap.  Is there a more specific problem you're encountering, or a fragment of a chart you're working on but having trouble with?

Comment: Hello David, thank you for for comment. 
Indeed, I was thinking about using ConfigMap, but I had no idea how to pass my template into the configMap. I updated my initial post to add the template content that I have.